# Get rid of color background R Markdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I added a tabset "Report Overview" and "Breakdown" and I also added another tabset so that I could create buttons to show different tables.

For some reason, when I knit mt R markdown file there is a color background that I can figure out how to remove. I tried using "transperent" inside the tabset but still don't work.

Here is the color background I want to remove on my file: [image]

```
---
title: "Predictions"
output: 
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---

##  {.tabset}

### Report Overview 

We show a scatter plot in this section.


### Breakdown  

We show the data in this tab.


<style>
.tablink {
  background-color: #1FA8ED;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 60px 65px;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 80%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #1FA8ED;
}

.active {
  background-color: #1FA8ED;
  color: white;
}


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
 }
 
 function openTab(evt, tabName, sourceImg) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    document.getElementById('source-img').src = sourceImg;
}
 
</script>

#### Sources {.tabset .transparent}



<div style="float:left;width:125px;">
<img id="source-img" src="C:/Users/leonardo.urbiola_fox/Downloads/leads_projections/Predictions2/graph.png" style="width: 125px; height: auto; display: block; margin: auto;"/>
</div>

<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'ads', 'C:/Users/leonardo.urbiola_fox/Downloads/leads_projections/Predictions2/googleads.png'  )">Google Ads</button>

<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'lsa', 'C:/Users/leonardo.urbiola_fox/Downloads/leads_projections/Predictions2/googlelsa.png')">Google LSA</button>


<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'wgl', 'C:/Users/leonardo.urbiola_fox/Downloads/leads_projections/Predictions2/WeGetLeads.png')">We Get Leads</button>

<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'pest', 'C:/Users/leonardo.urbiola_fox/Downloads/leads_projections/Predictions2/PESTNET.png')">PestNet</button>

<div id="ads" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Google Ads</h3>
```

Comment: remove the instances of `background-color: #1FA8ED;`, which is the [hex color for that shade of blue](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%231FA8ED&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: thank you for your answer @jpsmith I use background-color: #1FA8ED to color the buttons. what could I do to keep the color of those buttons

Comment: @LeonardoUrbiola just remove it from where it colors the tabs then and keep it for the buttons